# Computing SVD of matrix with repeating rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, svd

I have a gigantic matrix whose svd needs to be computed.
However the matrix actually is made of rows and columns with repetitions.

The matrix of unique rows and columns, $M_{ij}$ is small enough to be easily handled.
The row $i$ repeats $R_i$ times and column $j$ repeats $C_j$ times.

Given (M,R,C) is it possible to reconstruct the singular values of the full matrix from the singular values of $M$ alone ?

Comment: There isn't a (simple) relation between them. Each additional row/column weights the values closer to the values of that row. The problem is equivalent to trying to deduce the eigenvalues of $A+B$ from those of $A$ and $B$.